# Does flatbuffer guaranty the same for the identical data?

Tags: flatbuffers

We just got a strange problem, the same code and input data, the generated flatbuffers could be different when they are called twice. Of course, it is most probably caused by some bug by us, but we cannot help asking the question, whether flatbuffer guaranties the same for identical input data?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlatBuffers certainly is deterministic, i.e. if you call it in exactly the same order with the same data, it should generate the same buffer, bit for bit. I'm guessing either something was different about the data or about the order of creation.

Also, different implementations for different languages may generate slightly different buffers.